# ¿Como configurar por defecto un texto muuuuuy largo en un campo en Odoo8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

Buenos días,

Estoy trabajando con el módulo de selección y reclutamiento de odoo8... el problema es que tengo un texto demasiado largo (de una página más o menos) 
y los jefes odian estar copiando/pegando ese texto cada vez que realizan un nuevo registro...

Este es e siguiente texto:

" Tienden a ver el lado bueno de las cosas, son optimistas en cuanto a las posibilidades que les ofrece el futuro, les resulta fácil pasarlo bien y enfrentan con ecuanimidad los altibajos de la existencia. Las personas que obtienen un puntaje elevado en MODIFICACIÓN toman su vida en sus manos y hacen que las cosas sucedan en lugar de mantenerse pasivamente en espera. Se ocupan diligentemente de modificar su entorno e influyen en los acontecimientos a fin de que éstos satisfagan sus necesidades y deseos. Las personas que obtienen un puntaje elevado en INDIVIDUALISMO están orientadas a satisfacer sus propias necesidades y deseos; es decir, procuran realizarse plenamente ellas mismas en primer lugar, se preocupan muy poco del efecto que pueda tener su conducta en los demás, y tienden a ser a la vez independientes y egocéntricas.

Recurren a los demás en procura de estimulación y aliento. Sus amigos y colegas son para ellas fuente de ideas y orientación, de inspiración y energía; las ayudan a mantener alta su autoestima y las confortan con su presencia. Derivan sus conocimientos de lo tangible y lo concreto; confían en la experiencia directa y los fenómenos observables más que en el uso de la inferencia y la abstracción. Lo práctico y lo "real", lo literal y lo fáctico son lo que las hace sentir cómodas y les inspira confianza. Prefieren procesar los conocimientos por medio de la lógica y el razonamiento analítico. Sus decisiones se basan en juicios desapasionados, impersonales y "objetivos" y no en emociones subjetivas. Son muy organizadas y predecibles en su manera de abordar las experiencias de la vida. Transforman los conocimientos nuevos adecuándolos a lo ya conocido y son cuidadosas, cuando no perfeccionistas, incluso al ocuparse de pequeños detalles. En consecuencia, se las considera ordenadas, minuciosas y eficientes.

Buscan estimulación, excitación y atención. A menudo reaccionan con vivacidad ante situaciones de las que son testigos, pero por lo general su interés se desvanece rápidamente. Frecuentadoras de la alta sociedad, brillantes y simpáticas, también pueden ser exigentes y manipuladoras. Las personas que obtienen un puntaje elevado en FIRMEZA tienden a creer que son más competentes y talentosas que quienes las rodean. A menudo son ambiciosas, egocéntricas y seguras de sí mismas, y no tienen pelos en la lengua. Es probable que los demás las vean como arrogantes y desconsideradas. Las personas que obtienen un puntaje elevado en CONFORMISMO es probable que sean honradas y tengan autodominio. Su relación con la autoridad es respetuosa y cooperativa, y tienden a actuar con formalidad y buenas maneras en las situaciones sociales. Es improbable que dejen traslucir su personalidad o que actúen espontáneamente. Las personas que obtienen un puntaje elevado en CONTROL son enérgicas y a menudo dominantes y socialmente agresivas. Tienden a verse a sí mismas como intrépidas y competitivas. Para ellas, la gentileza y las demostraciones de afecto son signos de debilidad, y por lo tanto las evitan, mostrándose obstinadas y ambiciosas.

Recurren a los demás en procura de estimulación y aliento. Sus amigos y colegas son para ellas fuente de ideas y orientación, de inspiración y energía; las ayudan a mantener alta su autoestima y las confortan con su presencia. Derivan sus conocimientos de lo tangible y lo concreto; confían en la experiencia directa y los fenómenos observables más que en el uso de la inferencia y la abstracción. Lo práctico y lo "real", lo literal y lo fáctico son lo que las hace sentir cómodas y les inspira confianza. Prefieren procesar los conocimientos por medio de la lógica y el razonamiento analítico. Sus decisiones se basan en juicios desapasionados, impersonales y "objetivos" y no en emociones subjetivas. Son muy organizadas y predecibles en su manera de abordar las experiencias de la vida. Transforman los conocimientos nuevos adecuándolos a lo ya conocido y son cuidadosas, cuando no perfeccionistas, incluso al ocuparse de pequeños detalles. En consecuencia, se las considera ordenadas, minuciosas y eficientes. "

¿Como puedo poner ese texto completo como valor por defecto en un campo texto de Odoo8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buenas tardes,

ya conseguí resolver el problema y por ello publico la solución

Actualmente existen 2 formas de configurarlo 
1) A través de la interfaz de usuario
2) En el archivo de código, en este caso hr_recruitment.py

1) A través de la Interfaz de Usuario Odoo8:

1. Activar modo desarrollador
2. Abrir la vista formulario y buscar el campo al que se le desea asignar el valor por defecto.
3. Del modo desarrollador, en el menú desplegable click en `set defaults`
4. En la lista desplegable de la ventana emergente, seleccione su campo y haga clic en `save defaults`. Opcionalmente puede especificar si este valor predeterminado debe ser sólo para usted o para todos los usuarios.

Alternativamente, si insistes en tenerlo en tu código de python, solo elige una manera conveniente de almacenar el valor largo (en un archivo separado a lo largo de tu módulo personalizado, o como una variable dentro de tu módulo, en algún lugar del db, etc.) y Entonces anula el módulo, declarando el valor por defecto del campo

`long_text = """A very
               long
               text"""
    field_name = fields.Char(default=long_text)`